# How to modulo through list and move its contents

Tags: python, list, modulo

How does modulo work with the list?

This function returns a new distribution `q`, shifted to the right by `U` units.  If `U = 0`, `q` should be the same as `p`.

```
p = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

def move(p, U):
    U = U % len(p)
    q = p[-U:] + p[:-U]
    return q

print(move(p, 1))
```

The code output is correct: `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`

How would one describe the mathematical steps of this python code in layman's terms?

**solved**.

To better understand how the Modulo works I wrote this code and inspected the output:

`for i in range(40):
     print('the number : ', i)
     print('number % 5 : ', i%5)`

Modulo is the remainder, but not simply the remainder.  Another user put it in this inspiring way:

Thinking of 24 hours in a day,

> You can think of all hours in history wrapping around a circle of 24 hours over and over and the current hour of the day is that infinitely long number mod 24. It is a much more profound concept than just a remainder, it is a mathematical way to deal with cycles and it is very important in computer science. It is also used to wrap around arrays, allowing you to increase the index and use the modulus to wrap back to the beginning after you reach the end of the array.

Comment: `q = []` not that useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0] # asign a list to the variable p

def move(p, U): # define a new function. Its name is 'move'. It has 2 parameters p and U
    q = [] # Assign an empty list to the variable q
    # len(p) returns the size of the list. In your case: 5
    # You calculate the remainder of U / len(p) ( this is what modulo does)
    # The remainder is assigned to U
    U = U % len(p)
    # p[-U:] gets U items from the list and beginning from the end of the lis
    # e.g. [1,2,3][-2:] --> [2,3]
    # the second part returns the other side of the list.
    # e.g. [1,2,3][:-2] --> [1]
    # These two lists are concatenated to one list, assigned to q
    q = p[-U:] + p[:-U]
    # The new list is returned
    return q

print(move(p, 1))
```

Let me know if you need any further explanation to one part

Answer (score 0):

Modulo does not work with the list, modulo only affects the index value U.  U is used to split the list in two here:

```
p[-U:] + p[:-U]
```

what modulo does for you is to make sure that U stays between 0 and len(p)-1, without it you could input a really large value for U and get an index error.

also note, in your code, the line

```
q = []
```

does nothing as q is created again in the step:

```
q = p[-U:] + p[:-U]
```

Comment: Is it bad coding practice to assign `q = []`?  Why?

Comment: yes. its totally unnecessary, so it just clutter.

Comment: might as well write a=1 instead.